# Find replace value in nested dictionary

Tags: python, dictionary, nested

I have a nested dictionary like this

```
{ "car1": {"engine": "+", "paint": "0", "transmission": "-"}
"car2": {"engine": "-", "paint": "+", "transmission": "0"}
```

Question 1:  How do I replace the symbols ("+" ,"-", "0") to numbers like `1`, `0`, or `-1`?

Question 2:  Is there a way to add `car1` and `car2` to get a summary once the symbols are replaced by numbers?

Comment: Assuming that your `dict` is held in variable `d`, use: `d['car1']['engine'] = 1` etc.

Comment: Thanks!  The dictionary is quite long and there is no guarantee that "Engine" will always have value of "+", it could have "-", etc.  I am looking for a global replace method regardless of keys for all +, -, etc

Answer (score 0):

First, here's the part for replacing the symbols:

```py
dictionary = { "car1": {"engine": "+", "paint": "0", "transmission": "-"}, "car2": {"engine": "-", "paint": "+", "transmission": "0"}}
numbermap={"-": -1, "0": 0, "+": 1}

for car in dictionary.values():
    car["engine"] = numbermap[car["engine"]]
    car["paint"] = numbermap[car["paint"]]
    car["transmission"] = numbermap[car["transmission"]]
```

On the first two lines, we are creating the dictionary itself and the numbermap dictionary. We will later use this to easily convert the symbols to numbers. Do note that I've added a comma and closing parenthesis to your dictionary.

Next we are iterating over all values. The `dictionary.values()` method is just returning all values of the dictionaries, thus the nested dictionaries we need.

Finally, we are updating each dictionary's values. We are using the numbermap dictionary to find the number we need. Afterwards we assign the corresponding value in the dictionary to that number.

Then, here's the code for summing up the dictionary, assuming that it is already in numbers:

```py
total={"engine": 0, "paint": 0, "transmission": 0}

for car in dictionary.values():
    total["engine"] += car["engine"]
    total["paint"] += car["paint"]
    total["transmission"] += car["transmission"]
```

First, we are initialising the resulting dictionary. Later, we will add the values to this dictionary to get our result.

Next, we are adding the values of each dictionary to our total dictionary. After the loop, the total dictionary will contain the sum of all values from the dictionaries.

If you only need the sum of all dictionaries, we can contract both code pieces into one:

```py
dictionary = { "car1": {"engine": "+", "paint": "0", "transmission": "-"}, "car2": {"engine": "-", "paint": "+", "transmission": "0"}}
numbermap={"-": -1, "0": 0, "+": 1}
total={"engine": 0, "paint": 0, "transmission": 0}

for car in dictionary.values():
    total["engine"] += numbermap[car["engine"]]
    total["paint"] += numbermap[car["paint"]]
    total["transmission"] += numbermap[car["transmission"]]
```